# Bring data periodically from Linked Database in SQLServer 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, database, synchronization

We are developing a system on PHP with SQL Server 2008. Is a system that must work with the invoices stored in another SQL Server instance, that I have linked to my Database using sp_addlinkedserver.

The problem is that I think I need to have it loaded locally (because of performance). Si I'm thinking to make a my own "invoices" table, and two times per day somehow bring the data from the linked table to the locally stored one.

How can I program SQL to do this every X amount of time?
What approach I should use to program the importing?

It first I though to make my own script to do this, but I would preffer to have SQL Server to handle this, but that depends on your opinion :)

Thnak you!
Guillermo

**NOTE: Replication sounds overkill for me.. I dont need to have real-time synconization. Neither I need to update the database, just read.**

Comment: Sounds like a great case for Sql server replication. In that case the "master server" wouldn't be linked though.

Comment: Replication sounds overkill for me.. I dont need to have real-time synconization. Neither I need to update the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use replication to copy the data.  However, it may take more administration than you're planning.  Replication is great for managing a consistent and timely copy of the data.

Another option is to setup a SQL Server job that will run a SQL script to insert into your target table using a select from your linked server.

You could also use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).  You would create a SSIS package where you would build a data flow that transfers your data from the source table to the target table.  You wouldn't need a linked server for this approach, because your data sources are defined within the SSIS package.  And, you can use a SQL Server job to schedule the package run times.

Comment: SQL Server Job + SQL Script seems the simpler approach (and the one that sounds better to me :)). I was thinking something like this but I didnt know how could this be called. However, do you consider that approach would have any disvantage over the other ones you mention?

Comment: @Guillermo, I think the Job + SQL Script is good choice too.  Replication can provide the timely solution, but you may not need it.  SSIS helps develop complex solutions, with error handling, etc.  SQL script puts the responsibility on you for data accuracy.  Your script, or procedures, must handle issues of data duplication,  missing data and other unexpected problems.